# how to set a live wall paper by program?

Tags: android

I want to set one specified live wallpaper for my device, so I imitate the LiveWallpaperPreview.java which is in the LivePicker application.
My code is:

```
  public void setLiveWallpaperClick(View v) {

   Intent intent = new Intent(WallpaperService.SERVICE_INTERFACE);
   intent.setClassName("com.android.wallpaper", "com.android.wallpaper.galaxy.GalaxyWallpaper");
try {
    mWallpaperManager.getIWallpaperManager().setWallpaperComponent(
            intent.getComponent());

} catch (RemoteException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    // do nothing
} catch (RuntimeException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
    finish();
}
```

And the permission in the manifest.xml is:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
```

But It can't work in my application. Is the code right?

Comment: Are you replacing the current wallpaper with desired wallpaper? For example if you have some another downloaded wallpaper and you know hes package name, can you set that one via your application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you! I have found the root cause: The code is right. But the apk must be push to /system/app directory, it can work. If the apk is installed in /data/app, it can not work. I think there is some different permissions between /system/app and /data/app.

Comment: so waht's the solution ??

Answer (score 0):

use following code to set custom live wallpaper :

> Intent intent = new
>   Intent(WallpaperManager.ACTION_CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER);
>         intent.putExtra(WallpaperManager.EXTRA_LIVE_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT,
>                 new ComponentName(this, MyWallpaperService.class));         startActivity(intent);

with additional permission suggested above by @Judy

here MyWallpaperService is custom wallpaper service.